Cannot use Google Assistant, Google app loading and nothing happens
I can't use my Google Assistant or "Hey, Google" anymore because it keeps taking me to the Google app and says loading for less than a second, that's all.
I can't even command it anymore even when I'm driving and I have tried everything, even wrote Google an email, still no response.
